# In OpenAPI 3.0/Swagger, how can I refer to the selected server?

Tags: api, swagger, openapi

In my `swagger.yml`, I have the following:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
servers:
  - url: https://dev.myserver.com/v1
    description: dev
  - url: https://www.myserver.com/v1
    description: production
```

And in one of the examples of my `requestBody`, I want to refer to the selected server. I tried something like this but it's giving an error that it's not able to reference to the selected server URL:

```
examples:
   TestExample:
      value:
         server:
            $ref: #/server/url   # This is giving an error that it's not able to reference the selected URL
```

In OpenAPI 3.0, how can I refer to the selected server?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're actually trying to achieve here? Request body `examples` are for, well, request body payload examples. Your example implies that the request body includes the server URL e.g. `{"server": "https://www.myserver.com/v1"}` - is this actually the case?

Comment: @Helen Yes, that's right. I have a callback URL in the payload and I want the URL in the example to reflect the selected URL. What I hope to achieve is to concatenate the selected server URL with a path. For eg: `{selected-server-url}/callback/path`